# Invalid bean definition with name 'mongo' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'mongo.port' in string value "${mongo.port}"

Tags: spring

I get the exception

```
 Invalid bean definition with name 'mongo' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'mongo.port' in string value "${mongo.port}"
```

when I try to deploy my application

The main point is I try to use property place-holders to be replaced with values from a properties file. Coud you indicate what is missing ?

my application context is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  ...>

<util:properties id="propertiesFile" location="classpath:properties/base.properties"/>

<import resource="mongodb-config.xml"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
<property name="scopes">
    <map>
        <entry key="session">
            <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope"/>
        </entry>
    </map>
</property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

my base.properties is

```
 mongo.host=${profils.mongo.host}
 mongo.port=${profils.mongo.port}
 mongo.dbname=${profils.mongo.dbname}
```

and the mongodb-config.xml is

```
<mongo:mongo host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="${mongo.dbname}" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
            <property name="writeConcern">
                <util:constant static-field="com.mongodb.WriteConcern.SAFE" ></util:constant>
            </property>
</bean>
```

Furthermore, in the pom.xml there is

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
     <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>

        </resource>
    </resources>

    <filters>
        <filter>
            src/main/filters/filter-default.properties
        </filter>
    </filters>
     <finalName>base</finalName>
</build>
```

and the filter-default.properties is:

```
profils.mongo.host=127.0.0.1
profils.mongo.port=27017
profils.mongo.dbname=base
```

EDIT:

in the target folder,

The values are correctly replaced

```
mongo.host=127.0.0.1
mongo.port=27017
mongo.dbname=base
```

but they do not seem to be taken into account

Insted of location="classpath:properties/base.properties", I tried to use

```
 <util:properties id="propertiesFile" location="file:///D:/base/target/base/WEB-INF/classes/properties/base.properties"/>
```

or

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="file:///D:/base/target/base/WEB-INF/classes/properties/base.properties"/>
```

But that did not work

Comment: I don't know `util:properties`, but I would use `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />` like this : http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/#xml . As a bonus, you can also enable/disable error reporting when encountering "resource not found".

Comment: I took your remark into account and updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use XML config anymore as I switched to Java config; but in an old project with XML config, I was using something like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans>
  <bean id="myBean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesMode" value="2" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations"><list>
      <value>classpath:foobar.properties</value>
    </list></property>
    <property name="properties"><props>
      <prop key="aProperty">value</prop>
    </props></property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

And it seems that it worked, but it was in its own XML file, which was in turn included. I don't think that the reasons why your variable are not found.

Comment: Thank you ! I had two properties files and the problem stemed from this, so I used your template, and put  <value>classpath:foobar.properties</value>
 <value>classpath:foobar2.properties</value>
in the list, and it worked